# OCaml pattern matches values of type exp, but should match values of type 'a list

Tags: ocaml

i have to do a program in ocaml that a Node with a string and a int
is my first program in ocaml and in the web there isn't a lot of information

```
type tree = string*exp*tree*tree ;;
type exp = Etree of tree |  Int of int ;;

let eval (e:exp) = 
  match e with
    | []->[]
    | Int _ -> e
    | Etree(n) -> match n with
      | Node(s, i, t1, t2) -> eval i
;;

let t : Etree = Node("a", Int 1, Empty, Empty)

eval t;;
```

the IDE tell me that:

```
Type exp defined.
Toplevel input:
    | Int _ -> e
      ^^^^^
This pattern matches values of type exp,
but should match values of type 'a list.

Toplevel input:
let t : Etree = Node("a", Int 1, Empty, Empty)
        ^
Syntax error.
```

can someone tell me why?

Comment: This looks a lot like an assignment question. If this is the case, you should probably ask your teacher to have a look at your code.

Answer (score 4):

The line `| []->[]` in your pattern matching makes the compiler believe that e is a list. You should remove that line (why do you have it in the first place?).

This won't be enough to correct the problem, as you use that `Node` constructor that you didn't declare. You should change your declaration of tree.

Now one other problem is that `tree` references `exp` even though `exp` hasn't been declared yet. That's problematic.

So, you should change your initial types declaration to:

```
type tree = Node of string * exp * tree * tree
and exp = Etree of tree |  Int of int ;;
```

Note the use of the `and` keyword before `exp`. That tells the compiler that the two type definitions are mutually recursive (that is, they mention each other).

Your second problem comes from the fact that types and constructors are two different things.

- Types are an annotation on value, they are lowercase and on the left of the `=` in type declarations.
- Constructors are values, they are Uppercase and on the right of the `=` in type declarations.

`exp` is a type, `Etree` is one of its constructor.

So your declaration of the value t should be

```
let t : exp = Etree( Node("a", Int 1, Empty, Empty) )
```

At this point, the compiler will complain about `Empty` (and rightfully so) because `Empty` is not part of your `tree` definition. Just the constructor to `tree` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like there are several issues with your types.

The error message you receive is because you try to match e, which has type exp, to the pattern []. But [] is an empty list and not a constructor of exp. If you want to have emptry expressions you need to provide a seperate constructor for that. For example

```
type exp = Etree of tree |  Int of int | Nothing;;
```

Additionally you later seem to want to provide an Empty tree to the tree t. I would expect you to get another error there because again Empty is not a value of type tree. Lastly I think you want to give the term t the type exp and not Etree beause Etree is a constructor for expressions and not a type.